# Why is JMock 2.6.0 a release candidate?

Tags: jmock

I rolled out JMock at our company, and many folks are using it with success.  The version we are using is the latest stable release, which is 2.5.1.  That was released in August 2008.  Since then, two release candidates came out, 2.6.0RC1 and RC2 in 12/08 and 9/10, respectively.  That seems like a long time for a release to be a "candidate."  I'd like to update to 2.6.0, but my company is hesitant to use a product that is not a "stable" release.  I share their concerns.

I have two questions about this.  First, for anyone using the 2.6.0 RC1 or RC2 releases, have you found any evidence of instability in these versions?

Second, and this is more for the folks who created the tool, why is 2.6.0 considered still a release candidate and are there plans to release a "stable" 2.6.0?

Thanks!

Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.6.0.RC2 seems to be perfectly stable. I'd have no issues with using that in anger.

I understand there are plans to push 2.6.0 to a full release, and that it's just a matter of free time to do it...

Answer (score 1):

We're trying to get a release out but are short of maven help